# Connect combinantional block to JK Flip Flop

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, logic-gates

How can i connect combinantional block to JK flip flop in scheme like this:
[image]

Function i want implement is 3rd column from first image. That is truth table but i think it's wrong how i get values for x1' and x2'

[image]

Implementation:

Comment: Just do a simple truth table for each of X(I)1 and X(I)2 against X1 and X2 separately. I just did it and it is pretty simple.

Comment: Hello Peter, can you post picture of your truth table? I still don't get what should to do with 0 and 1 in this function.

Comment: @PeterSmith Your truth table looks like this? https://s32.postimg.org/fuo8jmg79/tablle1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Take your inputs (X1, X2) and map them to each of \$X_i1\$ and \$X_i2\$ for a truth table

$$\begin{array}{cc|c|c}
\text{X1} & \text{X2} & \text{X_i1} & \text{X_i2} \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

That yields

\$X_i1\$ = \$\bar X1 \cdot \bar X2\$ + \$X1 \cdot \bar X2\$ + \$ X1 \cdot X2\$

\$X_i2\$ = \$\bar X1 \cdot \bar X2\$ + \$\bar X1 \cdot X2\$ + \$X1 \cdot X2\$

For \$X_i1\$ this becomes:

\$\bar X1 \cdot \bar X2\$ + \$ X1(\bar X2+ X2)\$

As the term in parenthesis evaluates true at all times (a variable OR its complement is always true), we can eliminate it. The first term, by using [DeMorgan's theorem](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electronic/demorgan.html) becomes:

\$\overline {X1+X2}\$ so the entire solution for this term is

\$\overline {X1+X2} + X1\$

Doing the same for \$X_i2\$:

\$X_i2\$ = \$\bar X1 \cdot \bar X2\$ + \$\bar X1 \cdot X2\$ + \$X1 \cdot X2\$

This becomes

\$\bar X1 \cdot \bar X2\$ + \$ X2(\bar X1 + X1)\$

Using the same methodology as before, this simplifies to

\$\overline {X1+X2} + X2\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkvhgI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>